# How to replace URLs not within a href tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have a situation where I have text which contains URL links. The links are in 2 forms

1. www.stackoverflow.com
2. <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack over flow</a>

I am trying to create a simple function that uses regex that will wrap all links of type **1** with A HREF tag but leaving the other ones already wrapped a lone.

I have something like this but not successful.

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(<(\s*)a(\s)*href.*>.*<\/(\s)*a(\s*)>)/ig;
    var matches = exp.exec(text);
    for(var i=0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        var line = matches[i];
        if(!exp.test(line)) {
            var exp2 = /(\b(?:(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$])|”(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[^"\r\n]+”?|’(?:(?:https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.|ftp\.)[^'\r\n]+’?)/ig;
            text = text.replace("http://","");
                text = text.replace(exp2, "<a href=http://$1>$1</a>");
        }
    }

    return text;
}
```

It's not working but hoping someone could fix it :)

**EDIT**

The solution that fixed it, with the help of @MikeM answer

```
function replaceLinksSO(text) {
    rex = /(<a href=")?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]+\.)+[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]+/ig;   
    return text.replace(rex, function ( $0, $1 ) {
        if(/^https?:\/\/.+/i.test($0)) {
            return $1 ? $0: '<a href="'+$0+'">'+$0+'</a>';
        }
        else {
            return $1 ? $0: '<a href="http://'+$0+'">'+$0+'</a>';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: @Dve not really a duplicate. I am trying to replace plain URLs with links only on the condition that the plain URL is not wrapped with a href tag. Because I am doing this on an HTML document. The other regex actually completely fails my test case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without trying to analyze the complex regex and function above, here is an example implementation using a toy url matching pattern to illustrate a method of making such replacements

```
var str = ' www.stackoverflow.com  <a href="http://www.somesite.com">somesite</a> www.othersite.org '
    rex = /(<a href=")?(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\w+\.)+\w+/g;    

str = str.replace( rex, function ( $0, $1 ) {
    return $1 ? $0 : '<a href="' + $0 + '">' + $0 + '</a>';
});
```

You can alter the url matching pattern and insert e.g. `\s*` as required.

Comment: nice solution, this worked and replaced all my links (and ignored the already linked ones) on the string. I had to make it pre-pend http:// to the url though or the link would be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing patterns matching `/(https?:\/\/)?((?:www|ftp)\.[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]+?)[\r\n\s]+/` with `<a href="$1$2">$1</a>` would meet your requirement.

A better regex to match with will be `^(?!href="[^"\n\r\s]+?").*?(https?:\/\/)?((?:www|ftp)\.[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]+)$`

Comment: The central requirement was avoiding matching those urls that are *already* links.  I don't see that addressed here.

Comment: the regex requires the input to be ending in a space or new line.

Comment: I didn't notice that.  However, it doesn't seem like a very robust way of handling it.  What about URLs followed by punctuation, closing parentheses, etc?  Better to use a negative look-behind to make sure it is not a link (or better yet, use an HTML parser in conjunction with regexes).

Comment: @dan1111 but does javascript support look behind?

Comment: This worked, but it was only matching the first link in my test string.

Comment: @george_h what was your input text?

Comment: It is "test test test www.stackoverflow.com test test test http://www.cnn.com test test <a href=\"http://www.ibm.com/\">www.ibm.com</a> "

Comment: It is only replacing the first link and the first 3 "test" disappear